# how to query prismic slices and returning data from each slice

Tags: graphql, gatsby, prismic.io

I'm trying to use Gatsby's /___graphq debugger and the README file for [gatsby-source-prismic](https://github.com/angeloashmore/gatsby-source-prismic/blob/master/README.md) says you can return slices. So below I'm returning the slice with a name PrismicProductBodySteps.

```
{
  allPrismicHomePage {
        edges {
          node {
        data {
          seo_title
          body {
            __typename
            ... on PrismicProductBodySteps {
              }
            }
          }
        }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

**Can someone explain to me what ... on PrismicProductBodySteps means ?**

In a gatsby component I've seen this as an example.

```
body {
  ... on PrismicProductsBodySteps {
    ...ProductStepsFragment
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what the ...ProductStepsFragment means ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrismicProductBodySteps` would be a custom node type name representing a dynamic series of content blocks. That custom node type name is coming from a Prismic data model; yours will likely be different.

According to the [`gatsby-source-prismic`](https://github.com/angeloashmore/gatsby-source-prismic) documentation, using custom node type names requires you to figure out what they are first:

> The easiest way to get the type of nodes is to use the /___graphql
>   debugger and run the below query (adjust the document type and field
>   name).

```
{
  allPrismicPage {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        data {
          body {
            __typename
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have your custom node type name, you can use a GraphQL fragment to pull data specific to each fragment. Again, this would depend on how you have the fragments defined in your data model, but it would look something like this:

```
{
  allPrismicHomePage {
    edges {
      node {
        data {
          seo_title
          body {
            __typename
            ... on PrismicYourContentBlockOne {
              text {
                html
              }
            }
            ... on PrismicYourContentBlockTwo {
              text {
                html
              }
            }
            ... on PrismicYourContentBlockThree {
              text {
                html
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @staypuftman so I’m your example case the f Eat fragment would be PrismicYourContentBlockOne ?

Comment: Also in my case what does body {
  ... on PrismicProductsBodySteps {
    ...ProductStepsFragment
}. Mean. I presume PrismicProductsBodySteps is the fragment but if that’s the case then what is ...productStepsFragment.

Comment: `productStepsFragments` is the object being created by the custom node type `PrismicProductsBodySteps` (both of these are custom to your data model). `...productStepsFragment` is using the ES6 spread syntax, which basically calls and destructures the object at the same time.

Comment: Another way to think about it - picture your backend data model as an admin interface. It probably has a section within it (which would be `PrismicProductsBodySteps`). In your admin, you can make as many of these as you want - each one creates its own set of data represented by `productStepsFragment`

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: productStepsFragment could be any name as long as you use the same name in your component right ? Only the PrismicProductsBodySteps is unique to prismic not the fragment name ?

Comment: Well, both the `productStepsFragment` graphQL fragment and `PrismicProductsBodySteps` custom node type names come from the data model you setup on Prismic. They follow a pattern it appears, but you've got the concept: whatever name you give the data model would flow through to your component.